# Reading XML using XElement in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xelement

Can anyone please guide me on how to use XElement in Silverlight (C#) to read an XML file.

Thank You!

Comment: This question is not specific enough.  Which bit of the existing XElement documentation are you struggling to understand?

Comment: Hi Anthony. I added a reference to System.Xml.Linq dll. I can see it referenced in my silverlight application's references folder. Yet when I import it by doing [Using system.Xml.Linq] it says "are you missing an assembly reference" Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some example code:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = GetStatusReport();
}

public List<Status> GetStatusReport()
{
    List<Status> statusReport = new List<Status>();

    XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"Data/StatusReport.xml");

    statusReport = (from el in doc.Elements()
                    select GetStatus(el)).ToList();

    return statusReport;
}

private Status GetStatus(XElement el)
{
    Status s = new Status();
    s.Description = el.Attribute("Description").Value;
    s.Date = DateTime.Parse(el.Attribute("Date").Value);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Hi, intellisense cannot find any method Load or Parse for XElement!
Do I need to import any libraries apart from System.Linq?

Comment: You need to reference the System.Xml.Linq assembly then add `using System.Xml.Linq` in C#

Comment: I added a reference to System.Xml.Linq! however,  I cannot add "using System.Xml.Linq" it gives me the error, "missing assembly". When I see the references of my project, I can see a reference to System.Xml.Linq tho!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the static XElement.Load method to load XML e.g. from a file stream or directly from an XML file packaged into the .XAP.

Here's an example:
[link text](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/xLinkDoc06202007130827PM/xLinkDoc.aspx)

The MSDN page on XElement might also be helpful (Google: silverlight XElement class).

Cheers, Alex